# how do i get Url with gethostbyaddr when the ip is from a shared host?

Tags: php

Gethostbyname gives me an ip adress of een website when i use it in the browser i go to that website. 
If i try the same thing with a website that is on a shared host i get appachi is working correctly.

Here comes my question  when i use that ip with gethosbyaddr it gives me an url adress. Why is it that i dont get the website when i use the ip adress in the browser but when i convert it back i get a url that i get the correct website. How does he know what url to give me on a shared host. the ip adress has no 301 redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Apache uses virtual hosts, on a shared hosting server there are many websites which resolve to the same IP Address, the virtual hosts then decides which website to show depending on the URL.

So for example:

www.example1.com resolves to 1.2.3.4 - when entered in the address bar, 1.2.3.4 sees that the request is for www.example1.com and shows the files from /var/www/vhosts/example1.com/httpdocs

www.example2.com resolves to 1.2.3.4 - when entered in the address bar, 1.2.3.4 sees that the request is for www.example2.com and shows the files from /var/www/vhosts/example2.com/httpdocs

1.2.3.4 resolves to 1.2.3.4 - when entered in the address bar, 1.2.3.4 sees that the request is for 1.2.3.4 but that doesn't have a record in the virtual hosts, so it shows the 'Apache is working' page by default.

Answer (score 1):

Shared hosts are hosting several different domains on the same IP address. The way they distinguish between those domains is with the `Host` HTTP header. I.e. when visiting such a site, the browser explicitly sends which domain it's looking for in the HTTP request itself. That's why it doesn't work when you visit only the IP.

Therefore, converting such a domain to an IP address is trivial. The other way around is basically impossible, since there are many domains. Which you will get as answer is kind of a lucky draw.

Comment: But i get every time the same URL?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain, but I believe it uses the DNS system for this information and it will likely depend on the cache of your closest DNS server. In your tests you likely have used the same domain before and it's in the cache, but that's not guaranteed.